# Is Gas Model really sustainable?

Tags: gas

I'm running some mini contracts within our team and every time someone was bothered by the gas setting, or "intrinsic gas not enough", etc. Of course, I understand it's necessary to add gas into the blockchain to make it running for the specific behaviors in contract. It's in the design of Ethereum, and seems like reasonable.

However, I started to think, how possible this can sustain? In the future, the gas price may not get lower(even it won't get too high), and every mini function in a contract may take this burden to be executed, then how possible IoT or some micro-actions can be done within budget(e.g. unlocking a door may take some 1USD, is it reasonable as a resilient computing model?).

Comment: Welcome! I suggest editing the title to avoid being flagged as a primarily opinion-based question.  Please check http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

The gas price can be lowered by the community.  Those sending transactions can offer a lower gas price, and it would work if miners accept them.  This is a balance which the market and community will have to keep adjusting.  If gas price is too cheap there won't be miners; if gas price is too high no one will send transactions.